# Trouble finding an NJM2360D Boost Converter EAGLE library

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, library

I am doing a Senior Design Project for my Electrical Engineering degree. This project involves making a PCB. I am having trouble finding a specific library for EAGLE 7.7.0 software. The library that I need is for an NJM2360D Boost Converter. Does anyone know where I can get a library for this component? Please and Thank you!

Comment: That part is in a standard package - just make a symbol and foot print yourself. It should only take a few minutes to find another part in the same package, duplicate then edit it.

Comment: For any CAD system, my response to such questions is "make the required schematic and PCB symbols yourself".  If you do any amount of PCB design, you WILL have to make some of your own parts, so why not start now?  Most CAD programs have fairly easy-to-use schematic symbol and PCB footprint design editors.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you won't find a library for specific parts such as this. In the datasheet for your part, you'll find a "footprint" or "land pattern" or "mechanical dimensions", etc.

There are many tutorials for how to make a symbol and footprint in Eagle. If you're going to be designing a PCB, I would recommend you take the time to do this.

For your first footprint, I would suggest drawing it out by hand and calculating the dimensions once or twice to be sure you're correct. There is nothing worse than getting the PCB back to realize that your part doesn't fit.

Another recommended strategy is to print out your PCB on paper before ordering.

Comment: The part is in a standard DIP-8 or SO-8 so it should be easy to find an existing one.  I agree that even then it is worth checking.  I was bitten once where a footprint designer had not done the metric conversion correctly and the cumulative error over 16-pins was excessive.